# Single consumer for multiple queues in the Same JMS Server

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, amqp

I have a ActiveMQ AMQP Server running and I have a single consumer listening to the queue

Now i have three different producers

Producers 1 produces to Queue 1
Producers 2 produces to Queue 2
Producers 3 produces to Queue 3

All the three queues are from same server.

The question is

Can I make the Single consumer to listen to all these three queue??

If yes how to make it in Spring

Currently, my consumer is successfully by the following connection configuration

```
<bean id="blazeDestination" class="org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.QueueImpl">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="ctest2" />        
 </bean>
```

My Consumer is listening to the queue name ctest2

Can I make something lie

```
<bean id="blazeDestination" class="org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.QueueImpl">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="ctest2" />        
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="ctest3" />        
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="ctest4" />        
    </bean>
```

So that it listens to all the three queues!

Comment: Some of the message data appears to be missing

Comment: yup! Sorry.. changed it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my own question. During the time , I type this, it is not possible. We cannot make a consumer to listen to more than once queue.

Answer (score 1):

You could do [something like that](http://activemq.apache.org/composite-destinations.html) if you did not use the QPid client, but the ActiveMQ client.

Still, you can also do some [composite queue magic server side](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html#VirtualDestinations-CompositeDestinations) in XML configuration if you really need something like that. Just setup several composite queues with forward to a single physical queue that you read. It's not really the same thing, but it might (or might not?) solve your case.